# How to return a value from from a TWRequestHandler completion handler in iOS?

Tags: ios, twitter, ios5, twrequest

I'm trying to use the new twitter classes in ios5, but am having problems because of the completion handlers. How can I make a request in a method and have that return a value of something from the completion handler?

```
- (NSString) myMethod {

    TWRequest *request = ...

    [request performRequestWithHandler:

         ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

             myString = ...

         }];

     return myString
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to call another method or do whatever you need to do when its completed, I wouldn't recommend returning a value in there.

Comment: This would really be difficult as it's different classes calling various method from each other. I would have to make delegates and change a lot of code. Maybe it's the only way.